# Can I get the screenshot data as a file-like object or the image in bytes without saving any file?

Tags: python-mss

I want to send a screenshot over a discord webhook. I am using the [dhooks](https://github.com/kyb3r/dhooks/) module for this. To send a file, I need a "file-like object" so I want to get a file-like object without having the need to store the screenshot as a file. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added an example [in the documentation](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#get-png-bytes-no-file-output):

```py
import mss
import mss.tools


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # The monitor or screen part to capture
    monitor = sct.monitors[1]  # or a region

    # Grab the data
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

    # Generate the PNG
    png = mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: Though I have one more question, if we want to capture the screen of the first monitor, why don't we do `sct.monitors[0]` instead of `sct.monitors[1]`?

Comment: Here is the [explanation](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/api.html#mss.tools.mss.base.MSSBase.monitors) ;)

Comment: Understood it, thanks so much for all the help :)